# Unable to start apache

Tags: centos, networking, logs, apache-httpd, socket

I'm running CentOS7 in virtualbox on a mac (osx 10.9.3).

Ultimately, I want to access the website on my Guest VM from my Host. I can Ping and SSH to VM but I can't access the webpage when entering the VM's IP in Host browser. When running

```
systemctl status httpd.service
```

I get 2 errors:

1) "No listening sockets available". Netstat tells me there is no process on port 80. I'm not out of disk space. Error log is empty (for today) In "/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf" I put:

```
Listen 80
```

2) "Unable to open logs". In "/var/log/httpd" I did

```
chmod 777 error_log acces_log
```

I'm stuck; been trying to access this webpage for a day now.

Comment: what is the output of `journalctl --unit httpd.service` ?

Comment: logs begin at (today) 18:44 end at (today) 19:52

Comment: try running `systemctl start httpd` and then print the output of `journalctl --unit httpd.service`. also what is the output of `netstat -lnpt`? , also you need to make sure that `firewalld` is configured to allow access to the vm machine.

Comment: after 'systemctl start httpd' the log end changes to (today) 20:05. 'netstat -lnpt' gives 127.0.0.1:25, 0.0.0.0:22, ::1:25, :::8080, :::22. state all listen. (Can't copy from VM to Host, I hope u understand output.

Comment: So what's on 8080?

Comment: I don't quiet understand what it is, its PID 1781/master, tcp6, name 0, local adress is :::8080 (so it has no IP?), no foreign adress, state listen. Should I kill PID 1781?

Comment: master is a process of postfix (a MTA) you can stop it if you like with `systemctl stop postfix`. please make sure you have Apache installed `ls -l /usr/sbin/httpd`

Comment: wow, thanks! No more errors, 'systemctl status httpd.service' returns 'starting apache webserver' I killed postfix process. Apache is installed but still can't start using /etc/init.d/httpd start, that still returns no such file or directory. Starting to doubt wether apache is installed. yum install httpd is done though..